# Select group multiple records by specific condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table:

```
+----+-------+-------------+
| id | code  | value_check | 
| 1  |  p-01 |  OK         |
| 2  |  p-01 |  NOT OK     |
| 3  |  p-01 |  OK         |          
| 4  |  p-02 |  OK         | 
| 5  |  p-02 |  OK         |  
| 6  |  p-02 |  OK         |
+----+-------+-------------+
```

How can I select record which having `'OK'` group by code,but if there is one or more `'NOT OK'` on value_check then don't need to select

expected result:

```
code
p-02
```

i have tried my query can get the result but its very slow
this is my query :

```
SELECT code FROM table
   WHERE code 
NOT IN (SELECT code FROM table 
WHERE value_check = 'NOT OK' GROUP BY code)
GROUP BY code
```

any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether the total count is equal to the count of rows having value as `OK` using  `HAVING` clause.

**Query**

```
select `code` from `your_table_name`
group by `code`
having count(*) = sum(`value_check` = 'OK');
```

**[Find a demo here](http://rextester.com/YDEKO94422)**

Comment: You can simplify the `HAVING` clause to:  `count(*) = sum( value_check = 'OK')`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff : Yes, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try below with conditional aggregation

```
select code from table
group by code
having sum(case when value_check='NOT OK' then 1 else 0 end)=0
```

You can try it also with correlated subquery:

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4e81c5da1f70b3cd9c9b52231e46e560)

```
SELECT distinct code FROM cte1 a
   WHERE NOT exists (SELECT 1 FROM cte1 b where a.code=b.code and val = 'NOT OK')
```

Comment: your answer is good(+1), I couldn't understand what did somebody gave -1.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan, thank you, sometimes people put negative without understanding but in my case I found some people give negative without any reason

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.code
  FROM my_table x
  LEFT
  JOIN my_table y
    ON y.code = x.code
   AND y.value_check = 'not ok'
 WHERE x.value_check = 'ok'
   AND y.id IS NULL
```